# Refering a Parameter to another Parameter in testng.xml file

Tags: selenium, testng

I have the following in testng.xml

```
...
<parameter name="Empl_Name" value="Stephen" />
<test name="Employee Search test" junit="false">
    <parameter name="Valid_Empl_Name" value="${Empl_Name}" />
    <classes> 
          <class name="org.EmployeeClass" />
    </classes> 
</test>
```

The above is not working. My requirement is that I want to refer the Parameter `Valid_Empl_Name` with the above mentioned `Empl_Name`.
I want to reuse the `Empl_Name` parameter value in many of the test cases.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in TestNG but I'd be open to adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its quite complex, but there is a way.  If you build your project with Maven, there is a Maven plugin called `build-helper-maven-plugin`  that will let you pre-process the .xml file before the build starts.

I did this [in this project](https://github.com/djangofan/spring-mvc-testing-example/blob/master/pom.xml), but you can probably find better examples elsewhere.   Maven is no longer favored over Gradle anyways; maybe you can do the same thing with Gradle (or Groovy script).