# Follow up on refering-a-parameter-to-another-parameter-in-testng-xml-file

Tags: testng

Regarding this post, [Refering a Parameter to another Parameter in testng.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837273/refering-a-parameter-to-another-parameter-in-testng-xml-file/24561192#24561192): 
1. is the feature implemented? 
2. what is the alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I put an answer in the question you referred to.